# Flow allow concatenation with object.entries and string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a type like this:

```
type Cool = {
    [key: string]: number
}
```

Now, let's say I have an object with that type:

```
let my: Cool = {
    "asdf": 1,
    "jkl": 2
}
```

When I run `Object.entries(my)`, I get `[["asdf", 1], ["jkl", 2]]`. This seems normal. However, I want to combine each key to form a string, like this:

```
let mystring = "";
Object.entries(my).forEach(entry => {
    mystring = entry[1] + mystring;
});
```

I would expect that `mystring` is equal to "jklasdf" and it is. However, I get a flow error on the `mystring = ...` line. The error states:

> Cannot cast `Object.entries(...)[0][1]` to string because  mixed [1]
>   is incompatible with  string

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Weird, when I input your code in https://flow.org/try/, it says there are no errors.

Comment: According to the core typings from Flow, the result of `Object.entries` is an `Array<[string, mixed]>` so accessing `entry[0]` should yield a `string` ([reference](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2fbf2939a06455211ea1b79a5585ff239caea2d6/lib/core.js#L54)). Maybe you're trying to access `entry[1]` (which would have type `mixed`)?

Comment: Thanks @user11307804 ! I am accessing entry[1] in fact!

Comment: @RyanZ, see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2221 if you're still having trouble with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Object.entries` is typed as:

> static entries(object: $NotNullOrVoid): Array<[string, mixed]>

And when you try to use a value of a [`mixed`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/mixed/#toc-anything-goes-in-nothing-comes-out) type you must first figure out what the actual type is or you’ll end up with an error, so you can use Flow's [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) :

```
Object.entries(my).forEach(entry => {
  if (typeof entry[1] === 'number') {
    mystring = entry[1] + mystring;
  }
});
```

You could also just cast `entry[1]`:

```
Object.entries(my).forEach(entry => {
  mystring = Number(entry[1]) + mystring;
});
```

or add type to `entry` like this `entry: [string, any]` but note that **using** `any` **is completely unsafe, and should be avoided whenever possible.**

[**DEMO**](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCccMYAvGAN6ph1gDaA1nlgFxgDOGATgJYA7AOYBdDgICuAWwBGeHqgC+6GHgxgp7IiTKUa9MACIAhpwAmUQxwCMAGlr1DAKyYwrYAExKVajVm78whRGhgDcqADyMk54AMYYAHR4Arx8eJwAFJoAlAlQcDwAosaxABYZGcm8WNkUAHzUDnSaAYJCwQBy0nI8lSk8WAzWIrUA1H6twuGK2eFAA)

Comment: Why isn't `Object.entries` typed with generics like `Object.fromEntries`? If an object `o` of type `{[string]: number}` shouldn't the arguments of `Object.entries(o)` be inferred as `[string, number]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the algorithm, not the types.

First of all, if you want `mystring` to equal `"jklasdf"`, then you need to access the first index `[0]` like this `entry[0]`, because the first element in the array is the key of object, if that's what you're looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs...

So your code -regardless of the types- should be:

```js
let my = {
    "asdf": 1,
    "jkl": 2
}

let mystring = "";
Object.entries(my).forEach(entry => {
    mystring = entry[0] + mystring; // access the 0th element
});

console.log(mystring);
// jklasdf
```

So, now your flow types have no problem at all.
https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9nANlAvFA3gKCjqBtAawhAC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF0y6BXAWwCMIrMBfTJkQRgUDqVgJkaLLigAiAIbkAJgDMFZAIwAabLgUArAoi1QATAKEixEyrUapFCgNyYA8lyMQAxsAA6CDpqGghyAAoJAEoA9TgqAFElXwALCODqEFQAPgwDHHtQpzRMqhA8AAYmKABqcRAHegZ3fmjXIA

But, if I would recommend a more readable code to achieve the same result:

```js
let my = {
    "asdf": 1,
    "jkl": 2
}

let mystring = "";
   
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(my)) {
    mystring = [key, mystring].join('')
}

console.log(mystring);
// jklasdf
```

Or using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
let my = {
    "asdf": 1,
    "jkl": 2
}

const mystring = Object.entries(my)
                    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
                        return result = [key, result].join('');
                    }, "");

console.log(mystring);
// jklasdf
```